# How do you track a high score with PHP? (NO DATABASE, JUST SESSIONS)

Tags: php, session

Just need a simple block of code that will recognize the largest session score. Every time you win, score goes up by one. Every time you lose, it resets to zero. Thus, high score must be tracked. Used a boolean for game end, whenever you lose it sets to true.

```
if ($gameEnd = TRUE) {
      if ($_SESSION['score'] > $highscore) {
        $highscore = $_SESSION['score'];
      }
```

Expected: High score will stay as highest session scorte
Actual: resets to zero along with score

Comment: Is that pseudo code? If not, your conditional statement will always be TRUE.

Comment: Yes, before if statements that determine win or loss there is $gameEnd = FALSE;

Comment: it's missing an `=` for it.

Comment: Sorry that was just me writing the code for the question, on the file it's a double equals, still doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by the largest session score? Are you talking about multiple user sessions?

Comment: Largest = highest. Every time the user wins, score goes up by one using php session. When they lose, it resets to zero. So it counts successive wins.

Comment: Simply increment their scores (`$_SESSION['score']++;`)... What doesn't work?

Comment: That isnt the problem, the problem is how to save the highest score for when it resets to zero.

Comment: In the session variable? Just set `$highscore = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time after performing operation $_SESSION['score']++ assign to another session.

```
$_SESSION['score']++;
if ($_SESSION['score'] > $_SESSION['score_backup']) {
    $_SESSION['score_backup'] = $_SESSION['score'];
}
```

Perform your operation with $_SESSION['score'] (increase/decrease), now your high score is in $_SESSION['score_backup'].

*Note: Ofcourse do the assignment operation yourself.